# Lightsail Bitnami reboot resets the machine_hostname setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, hostname, amazon-lightsail

I have a running AWS Lightsail instance, with bitname and Wordpress running on it.
I have assigned it a static IP address.
After setting it up I have opened the console and configured the machine_hostname like this:

`sudo ./bnconfig --machine_hostname <domain>`

After this, the domain now works, and everything operates as expected..... Until the instance reboots. At that time the domain is lost, and I have to perform this again.

Not sure how to prevent this from happening on a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you run the bnconfig tool to configure the domain name in the application, you need to rename the tool so it's not run again when the instance is started/rebooted.

```
sudo ./bnconfig --machine_hostname <domain>
sudo mv ./bnconfig ./bnconfig.disabled
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/configuration/configure-custom-domain/

You can also update the WordPress' configuration with your domain (/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php)

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://DOMAIN/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://DOMAIN/');
```

You can learn more about that here

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/

Comment: So I actually followed the instructions in the FIRST link, which did not mention that a reboot would just reverse them (Which makes no sense by the way, why would they be reversed). 

I tried the second option (Without renaming BNConfig), and doing that still reverse the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE in the wp-config.php after a reboot.
Thus It APPEARS that it's a requirement to rename bnconfig, which I would prefer to avoid since I may use it later and forget the new name, plus renaming tools seems like a bad idea.

Comment: If you don't rename the bnconfig tool, it'll be run the next time you reboot the instance and it'll change the domain configuration in the WordPress' database. You need to rename it if you want to use a domain. You can run the bnconfig later by using this comand `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig.disabled YOUR_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <domain>`